# Conditional style class to xforms controls

Tags: xforms, orbeon

I would like to apply style class on conditional basis.

Lets say i have xforms:trigger button, i want to make this button readonly (disabled) when the read only flag is true.

```
<xforms:trigger appearance="minimal" class="xforms-readonly">
```

The clause `class="xforms-readonly"` i want to apply it conditionally.

Please suggest a way to do so.

Comment: <xforms:trigger appearance="minimal" class="xforms-{if(instance('data')/read-only='true') then 'readonly' else 'control'}"> works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standards-compatible way would be this:

```
<xforms:model>
  ...
  <xforms:bind nodeset="instance('data')/read-only" readonly=". = 'true'"/>
</xforms:model>
...
<xforms:trigger ref="instance('data')/read-only" appearance="minimal">
  ...
</xforms:trigger>
```